# Taking photos is slow

Tags: samsung, camera

I've a few month old Samsung Galaxy A51 (android 10) and it's camera needs couple of seconds (2-4) BEFORE taking any picture, which is just too long when I want to photo children.

My past phones were all from Samsung Galaxy A series and never had this issue.

Is there anything I can do to make taking photos faster?

Comment: Before or after the photo is actually taken. Try a different camera app or check the settings of your camera app if you find something that could cause this delay.

Answer (score 0):

Taking high resolution pictures needs to process the image data. Based on GPU, it may take a while, like ~ 2-3 seconds for ~ 14-20 Megapixel camera phone.
Some phones camera software may take several pictures to increase picture quality or prevent blurry photos using software, which also increase processing time.

**You can manually reduce the photo resolution from camera app settings, which may reduce overall processing time. Turn off HDR as well if not needed.**

Also try some 3rd party camera app and try which suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem is the time before taking the picture, not after.

Comment: Oh, so if it's a Camera app loading problem, that may be caused by running new/updated app on old hardware. Uninstall updates or try some lite Camera app.

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes with me. Make sure you have enough internal free space.

Since you are using a Samsung device, there is an option for device care in the settings. Click on 'Optimize now' it will close the unnecessary background apps and optimizes the memory. Still, if you are facing this issue try restarting your device.

Also, keep your device up to date because they keep on fixing various bugs with new updates.

Comment: I've 80 GB free from 128 GB